# cannot adjust rear volume playback levels in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio

I have my front jack and my rear jack playing simultaneously, my problem is that in speaker properties when I want to adjust the rear volume, it wont do anything and only the front volume control will adjust all 4 speakers the same time